# Emptiness on weak alternating automata

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, automata

I wanted to ask if there are algorithms (also already implemented) for checking emptiness of an alternating automaton in particular a weak alternating automaton.

Comment: I think you should ask on cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Comment: cstheory.stackexchange.com is for research-level questions in theoretical computer science,this issue is rather than practical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an implementation called ALASKA: http://www.antichains.be/alaska/ - you will also find links to the respective theory papers on that page.

Comment: The site you mentioned contains algorithm to determine nonemptiness on Buchi alternating automaton but i need algorithm for weak alternating automaton

Comment: Weak alternating automata are a special case of alternating Büchi automata. Just mark all states in a rejecting component of a weak alternating automaton as being rejecting in the Büchi semantics and make it accepting otherwise.